# Update when the user is not logged in

Tags: php, mysql

```
$timeNow = time();
$timeExpire = $timeNow + 10;
$User = $con->query("SELECT * FROM players WHERE Username='".$_SESSION['Username']."'");
$UserInfo = $User->fetch_object();

if($timeNow >= $UserInfo->TimeExpire) {

    echo "Wood Gathered";
    $con->query("UPDATE players SET Wood = Wood+5 WHERE Username='".$_SESSION['Username']."'");
    $con->query("UPDATE players SET Time = '".$timeNow."' WHERE Username='".$_SESSION['Username']."'");
    $con->query("UPDATE players SET TimeExpire = '".$timeExpire."' WHERE Username='".$_SESSION['Username']."'");

}
```

How can I make the following code work even the user is not logged in?

Like for example he comes back in 1 day and gets 1728 wood because 86400 (1 day) / 50 (get resources every 50 seconds) is equal to 1728.

Comment: Some RDBMSs allow you to `UPDATE players set Wood = Wood + 5` to every user, you run that every n minutes and forget about doing that inside the application, when the user logs in and stuff. Or you keep track on the last login time and calculate how many "expirations" were that.

Comment: I believe you need to re-think your code.

On this case you are programming a game, but you don't have just one user, so the best option you need to work with task queue, save the actions (get resources/time/etc) on another table and clean those items when ready.

Comment: How would I calculate how many expirations are there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sensing you're programing a game and since games need  to be real-time:
Create a file e.g `cron.php`  and include that file in every page. Inside that file put this:

```
<?php
$timeNow = time();
$timeExpire = $timeNow + 10;
$Users = $con->query("SELECT * FROM players WHERE TimeExpire<='".$timeNow."'");
while($UserInfo = $User->fetch_object()){
    $givenWood = $timeNow - $UserInfo->TimeExpire;
    $con->query("UPDATE players SET Wood = Wood+ {$givenWood}   WHERE Username='". $UserInfo->Username ."'");
    $con->query("UPDATE players SET Time = '".$timeNow."' WHERE Username='". $UserInfo->Username ."'");
    $con->query("UPDATE players SET TimeExpire = '".$timeExpire."' WHERE Username='". $UserInfo->Username ."'");
}

?>
```

Have in mind that I put this code just to give the idea how to do that.So, there might be something wrong with my logic in the code. (What you should do is get those users whom you can give some wood to them, calculate them time between now and last time you gave them their wood and  give them proper amount of wood).